# JQuery UI draggable image with containment. How to drag image out of its parent (containing) element

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

Users upload images, then they drag their uploaded images into place holders on the page. They are basically designing a layout of different images within a template grid.

I have written code to use draggable for images and droppable for the place-holders. That allows me to easily drop images into the place-holders. Once an image is in a place-holder, the image can be moved/dragged around so different parts of the image can be seen within the place-holder. The image (once dropped in the place-holder) becomes a new draggable that is contrained so the user can only move the image around as far as its edges.

Problem is: Once images are in their place-holders I want to drag them from one place-holder to another. But because they are sat within a parent element that clips them to the shape of the place-holder it's not so simple. My original thoughts were:

1. Detect when the mouse position (while dragging) is 10 pixels outside
   the place-holder
2. Clone the image and append the clone to the body 
   tag
3. Make the cloned image follow the mouse
4. When the user stops dragging (mouseup) over a
   placeholder, swap the images between the two place-holders (the one
   that  started the original drag and the one that triggered the
   mouseup).

Along those lines I wrote something that used mouseup on the placeholders and I kept track of the currently dragged image in a global variable. I have an example here: http://goo.gl/0cXCM

I am re-writing that example so I can also drag new images into the placeholders using Jquery UI droppable where possible. The droppable code is much easier to work with than the code in that example and allows me to "revert" an image and animate it back to the list if it is not dropped on a placeholder.

Points 1-3 above are simple but because the cloned image is not a real draggable initialised by real dragging, it won't "drop" on to a droppable place-holder. That's why I originally wrote it without droppables.

I have tried:

1. Making the cloned image a draggable and firing the
   mousedown/dragstart events on the clone using trigger.(not working)
2. Searching Stack Overflow for questions about starting drag, but what
   I found is mostly about starting drag from a click on another
   element.  I don't have a click to work with.

More info: the mouse is clicked, then moved and starts drag on the image in a placeholder.  While the mouse is still down and moves 10 px outside the placeholder, a cloned image is appended to the page. On mousemove, the position of the cloned image is updated.  All this time the mouse is still down.  The only thing (I think) that can identify the cloned image when it is dropped is a mouseup event on a placeholder.

Is there a better way to get this to work?
Can the cloned image be wired up to use some reasonably standard droppable code?

Comment: I would recommend rethinking the user interface. Thinking from a user's perspective that might be pretty confusing to have dragging for repositioning the image within its parent and dragging to place the image in a different parent. I would suggest maybe a button to enable/disable repositioning of the image in its parent and by default have dragging swap the placement of the image in the layout.

Comment: Have you tried the example url? It seems ok to me.  Also it's the way Apple do it in iPhoto for creating a photo book. I have researched various ways of doing it.  This one seems less clunky and won't require any instructions.

Comment: No, you're right. The example was very nice. I didn't look at the site originally